# Prototype.js: How can i return an array without all the methods Prototypes extends Array with?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, prototypejs

Is there a way to return a new version of an array/hash that does not contain all the methods/functions that prototype extends the array object with?

Example:

```
var myArray = $A();

myArray['test'] = '1';

myArray['test2'] = '2';

var myVariableToPassToAjax = myArray;
```

If I debug myVariableToPassToAjax it looks like this:

```
Array
(

  [test] => 1

  [test2] => 2

  [each] => function each(iterator, context) {
    ..........
    ..........
  }

  ...and all the other extended array functions
);
```

Is there a way to solve this? :-/

Morten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be using the Array properties of the Array anyway, so you could just return an object instead:

```
var o = {
    test1: '1',
    test2: '2'
};
```

Comment: This array is supposed to be sent via AJAX so I really just want an assoc array with keys and values..
Is there a way to accomplish that?

Morten

Comment: Is there a way to make a function that would make such a object for an assoc array that could also contain other arrays...
I guess my example was lacking a little detail...

Morten

Comment: In JavaScript, every object could be described as an associative array. There's nothing special about my example: it just creates a bog standard object and assigns properties to it, which can then be enumerted using `for...in`. Properties can be of any type, including Array.

Comment: I just did not see the possibilities in your example.. But I see it now!
You where totally correct all along... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Prototype extends the Array object's prototype, so it practically breaks the for(in) loops, and increases the risk that your own keys overlap. Start by reading why [JavaScript "associative arrays" are considered harmful](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/), and try [using an Object instead of associative arrays](http://blog.metawrap.com/blog/June6thIsJavaScriptArrayAndObjectprototypeAwarenessDay.aspx).

Sending an object via AJAX.Request is done by simply passing it as the "parameters" option:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj['test'] = '1';
myObj['test2'] = '2';
new Ajax.Request([url], {
    parameters: myObj
});
```

Comment: This was the solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: Well... It was allmost a solution!

This does not work...

var myObj = {};
var myObj2 = {};

myObj['test'] = '1';
myObj['obj'] = myObj2;

This will now only contain:

Array(
   ['test'] => 1
);

What am I doing wrong? Or will it just not work this way?

Comment: You could do something like this:
var myObj = {};
var myObj2 = {"test2": 2};
myObj['test'] = '1';
myObj['obj'] = myObj2;
new Ajax.Request([url], {
    parameters: {object: $H(myObj).toJSON()}
});
and then, on the server side, you will recieve the "object" parameter, which you can decode (json_decode if using PHP)